# Google cloud pub/sub integration with Standard java environment

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, google-cloud-pubsub

I am new to Google cloud platform and is working on developing Google app engine app in standard Java environment. For some of the part, I require using Google cloud pub/sub. Looking at the resources available, I feel that pub/sub can only be integrated in the flexible environment. Can someone please tell if it is possible to integrate pub/sub in the standard environment and if yes then how?

Answer (score 1):

For standard environment try this client https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/pubsub/v1.

IOM somewhat limited but it works.

For some reason I cannot find the official examples anymore, Google has probably removed them, which is pretty evil since the cloud pub sub library doesn't work in standard env plus the fact that cloud pub sub library is still in alpha which to is a reason not to use i t for production.

Found this, should help you on the way:

http://book2s.com/java/src/package/com/google/cloud/pubsub/client/demos/appengine/util/pubsubutils.html

Comment: I am about to add this part in my project, but I am unable to find a way to include this in Google endpoints java project. It would be great if you can point me to some resource that explains the way to integrate these two.

Comment: Seems like java8 is official now: https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/06/Google-App-Engine-standard-now-supports-Java-8.html, so I guess it's no issue anymore